# How to get an average of type int from a stream of int?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm writing a program in which I have to get the average delay for trains, but I'm having trouble as the stream must return an int (which means it will approximate the value). I'd prefer not to use a downcast.
The following is a code example

```
public int getAvgDelay(){
  return trainStop.stream()
                  .flatMapToInt(a->a.getDelays().stream())
                  .average().orElse(-1);
}
```

getDelays() returns a List of Integers with the delays for that train in a single station, I convert it to a stream, then the average will return a double, but I want to find a way to get an Int out of it.

Overall I'm having trouble with most streams where I have to return a single value after using some summarizing collectors, if you could give me a general rule on how to do it I would really appreciate it!

Comment: why can't you cast the result to int? Of course you will lose accuracy but that is what happens when you have double and you want integer from it.

Comment: There's no way to "get an int out of" the `average` function. You just have to convert it to an `int` either by casting/truncating or by using `Math.round`. (Note that `round` returns a `long` so you'll still have to cast it down to an `int`, which should be fine since the inputs were all `int`s.)

Comment: What I meant is that I don’t want to create a double and then cast it down to an int, I’d prefer to do everything at once with the stream if it’s possible

Comment: @Paglie98 1) it's not possible; 2) casting a double to an int is trivial, both syntactically and in terms of runtime cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one method using `Math.round()` to round the average value and cast it to an `int`:

```
public int getAvgDelay() {
    return trainStop.stream()
            .flatMapToInt(a -> a.getDelays().stream())
            .average().stream()
            .mapToLong(Math::round).mapToInt(i -> (int) i)
            .findFirst().orElse(-1);
}
```

But you should consider to return an Optional instead of a magic number (`-1`). If you do so you also can return the `OptionalDouble` or if you want a whole number an `OptionalLong` directly to prevent casting to an `int`.

You then can call your method like this:

```
int avg = getAvgDelay().orElse(-1);
```

Or use `.orElseThrow()` if you need an error state.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `average` method is `double` (actually it is an `OptionalDouble` but that is not the point) . If you want to return an `integer`, from your method, you have to cast the result to `int` explicitly. That happens because double is saved on 64 bits wheras integer on 32 bits. So you have to do the casting from `double` to `int` explicitly - by that you agree that you will lose some accuracy.

You might be interested in using methods like `Math::ceil`, `Math::floor` or `Math::round` to round up your average. Those methods return `double` (`Math::round` returns `long`) too so you will have to apply the cast explicitly too. However those methods will round up to the nearest integer - but still it will be of `double` type.