# Cannot Stream average() undefined for OptionalDouble

Tags: java

I'm using this code but eclipse shows an error saying
[stream() is undefined for the type OptionalDouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826671/how-to-get-an-average-of-type-int-from-a-stream-of-int)
The error shown by eclipse is

- The method stream() is undefined for the type OptionalDouble .

My code is something like this

```
        
        return IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6)
                .asLongStream()
                .flatMap(a -> a)
                .average()
                .stream()
                .mapToLong(Math::round)
                .mapToInt(i -> (int) i)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(-1);
```

I tried average().getasDouble() but that also didn't work. How do i fix the code ?
I can do one thing Double d=average().getasDouble() then apply Math.round(d) seperately.

Is it possible to fix the code after average().stream() in functional way without error ?
When average() return OptionalDouble and that can't be streamed by stream() , how do you go about it ?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: `Optional.stream()` was added in java 9, are you using 8? But the more glaring problem is  `.flatMap(a -> a)` - the mapper function should return `LongStream`, while your returns `long`, this won't compile regardless of the java version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`OptionalDouble.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#stream--) has existed ever since Java 9. You should check your Java version.

If you are unable to use a newer version of Java for some reason, you can implement `stream` yourself as a static helper method. What it does is very simple.

```
public static DoubleStream streamOfOptional(OptionalDouble d) {
    return d.isEmpty() ? DoubleStream.empty() : DoubleStream.of(d.getAsDouble());
}
```

```
return streamOfOptional(
        IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6)
            .average()
        )
        .mapToLong(Math::round)
        .mapToInt(i -> (int) i)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really want the `Optional`, with Java 8+ you can achieve the same using [Collectors.summarizingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction))  which will return an instance of the [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) class.  The `getAverage()` method will return a value  of `0.0` if no elements were present in the stream.

- Using [collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)),

  - first compute the statistics.
  - then apply your rounding and conversion methods and return the result.

```
return IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6).boxed().collect(
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                   Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue),
                   iss->(int)(Math.round(iss.getAverage()))));
```

Another alternative would be to use [Collectors.averagingInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)). Here I am using Stream since the values need to be boxed anyway to be collected.

```
return Stream.<Integer>of(1,2,3,4,5,6).collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
           Collectors.averagingInt(a->a),
           avg->(int)Math.round(avg)));
```

In both cases above, the `average` is computed as a `double` and `Math.round` returns a `long`.  So all that is necessary is to cast to an `int`.

One final note.  With `Stream.of` I typed witnessed the stream to `Integer` in case no value was provided so it would compile and return `0.0` average.  With `IntStream`, the type is declared so no witnessing was needed.  Whether this makes a difference depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Considering an *[arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean)* may be fractional, use a *[DoubleStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html)*.

```java
double average
    = Math.round(DoubleStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                             .average()
                             .getAsDouble());
```